# Check if customer is logged in (problems with cache)

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, login

I have a CMS page that only shows information when the customer is logged in. In this page I load a CMS block with this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="class_management/source.phtml"}}
```

In the beginning of the phtml file, to check if the customer is logged in or not, I use this:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
   //display content
}
```

The problem is, if the customer loads this page not logged in, the page will not show the content. If the customer log in and go back to the page, it will still not show the content until I refresh the cache.

Is there anyway to fix this?

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and my server has redis cache enabled.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set cache lifetime to 0 for your custom block in your layout xml.

Inside your theme, in **local.xml** file, inside  node add the code above:

```
    <block type="core/template" name="class_management_source" template="class_management/source.phtml">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>1</lifetime></action>
    </block>
```

In your CMS block you need to replace your block call with:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="class_management_source" template="class_management/source.phtml"}}
```

**Don't forget to clear your Magento Cache: System > Cache Magento > Flush Magento Cache**

Comment: Thanks for the help Jonathan, but I am not sure how to do that. I have a CMS Page that loads a CMS Block and this block is calling a phtml file. I didn't see an option to update the block layout with your code. Do I do that in the Magento Admin panel? I tried to update the CMS Page layout with this code, but didn't work...

Comment: Can you please show the code where you call the phtml file?

Comment: Sure, just updated the question with it: `{{block type="core/template" template="class_management/source.phtml"}}`

Comment: Would that be in my local.xml inside my theme folder? I tried that but still not working...

Comment: For the local.xml, where do I put the code? You said inside node, but I didn't get that...

Comment: Put your local.xml template inside your question please

Comment: It is a big file, around 600 lines...I put it here, is there helpful?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/brunomonteiro

Comment: Inside `<default>` add `<reference name="content"><block type="core/template" name="class_management_source" template="class_management/source.phtml">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
    </block></reference>`

Comment: Looks like is improving. I did what you said but the block was added to every page. So instead of doing in the `local.xml` I inserted this in `CMS > Page > Layout Update` in Magento Admin. That worked to insert the block just in the page that I need, but the cache is still having problem...even when was in the `local.xml`

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thank you for your help!! I was able to fix the problem. As I said, I did the update in my CMS Page instead of the local.xml, so it would not apply to the whole website. The only thing it needed to be fix in your answer was the layout update code. It should be `<action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>1</lifetime></action>` instead of `<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>`. Thanks again!

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro happy it works :) answer updated!

Answer (score 1):

Amm not sure but you can try below code, first flush the cache and check the things

```
{{block type="core/template" template="class_management/source.phtml" block_id="my-block" cache_lifetime=0 cache_tags="CACHE_TAG_MY_BLOCK" cache_key="my-block"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! What is "CACHE_TAG_MY_BLOCK" supposed to be? My block ID?

Comment: I tried without the "CACHE_TAG_MY_BLOCK" and didn't work...